# SUM with GROUP BY don't display zero sums

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to get data from a single table. I grouped by `CURR`. I have 12 condition listed. But some are zero.

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) AS TOPL,
    CURR
FROM XXX 
WHERE DATEPART(year, CONVERT(dateTime, DATE)) = 2018 
    AND DATEPART(month, CONVERT(dateTime, DATE)) = 1
GROUP BY CURR
```

This is returning 3 value. But I want 12 value including zero sums. I tried this with `CASE`, but I could not.

[image: Figure I want to show]

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have a sample of data that are in your table?
I don't understand, what is 0, CURR or AMOUNT ?

Comment: Create a help table with the values 1 to 12. RIGHT JOIN that table.

Comment: Is there any data in the table for the 9  entries you want that match the where clause you wrote?  Because SUM is applied to the data after it has been filtered.  So entries that weren't there won't appear in the result set.

Comment: No, any data other 9 entries

Comment: What @jarlh said

Comment: Show 0 if there is no data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the others have been trying to tell you is that you need a "list" of the CURR values you want to see in your results. Generally, these would come from another table in a properly normalized database. Do you have one? It seems not but it is worth asking. A properly normalized database would generally have one.

So how do you create this list dynamically? Let us assume that your existing table has at least one row for every CURR value you desire in your resultset - even if that row has a date that falls outside of your period of interest. We can use that to form this list and then outer join that list to your existing query that does the summing.

```
with curr_list as (select distinct CURR from dbo.XXX)
select curr_list.CURR, 
       sum(isnull(tbl.AMOUNT)) as TOPL 
from curr_list left join dbo.XXX as tbl 
   on curr_list.CURR = tbl.CURR 
   and tbl.[DATE] >= '20180101' 
   and tbl.[DATE] < '20180201'
group by curr_list.CURR
order by curr_list.CURR;
```

That should work assuming I made no typos. The CTE (named curr_list) creates the list of ID values that you want to see in your resultset. When you outer join that to your transaction data you will get at least one row for each CURR value. You then sum the amounts to aggregate those rows into a single row for each CURR value. Notice the change to the date criteria. Your original approach prevents the optimizer from using any useful indexes on that column.

If your existing table **does not** have a row for every value of CURR you want in your results, then you can simply change the cte and hardcode the values you desire.

Comment: It worked with a small modification @SMor. I declared new list include 1 to 12 numbers. Because some values empty for this year, but maybe next year there will be.

Comment: If you don't have all the value currently, you should still consider adding a new table with those values. It can be a temporary table in your request if you can't add a new table in you schema.

Answer (score 0):

I may get what you are trying to do.

If you have 12 CURR (I'm guessing currency?) and want to get the total amount of the transaction in January 2018 grouped by currency.

If this is the case, here is what you should try to do :

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) AS TOPL,
    CURR_TABLE.CURR
FROM CURR_TABLE 
LEFT JOIN XXX ON XXX.CURR = CURR_TABLE.CURR
WHERE DATEPART(year, CONVERT(dateTime, XXX.DATE)) = 2018 
    AND DATEPART(month, CONVERT(dateTime, XXX.DATE)) = 1
GROUP BY CURR_TABLE.CURR
```

That way you'll get all currency listed (even if no reccord of that currency is available for that month.

EDIT:

I don't like that kind of syntax when you can avoid it, but you can :

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) AS TOPL,
    CURR_TABLE.CURR
FROM (SELECT distinct CURR FROM XXX) CURR_TABLE
LEFT JOIN XXX ON XXX.CURR = CURR_TABLE.CURR
WHERE DATEPART(year, CONVERT(dateTime, XXX.DATE)) = 2018 
    AND DATEPART(month, CONVERT(dateTime, XXX.DATE)) = 1
GROUP BY CURR_TABLE.CURR
```

Comment: Left join.  So that CURR_Table entries that won't have matches will still be listed.  And move the WHERE clause into the Left Join.  Otherwise the records will still be filtered out as it's applied after the join.

Comment: You are right, I totally messed it up : I inverted my query.

Comment: There are any CURR table. I have single table. I must describe 12 variables in SQL. Show 0 if there is no data.

Comment: Well, select can't get values that are not in the table (or not in the filtered part of it). So either you create a list of the CURR (can be tempoary) or you join on a (select distinct curr from XXX).

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below query and compare with your expected output.

```
SELECT CURR, SUM(ISNULL(AMOUNT,0)) AS TOPL,
    CURR
FROM XXX 
WHERE DATEPART(year, CONVERT(dateTime, DATE)) = 2018 
    AND DATEPART(month, CONVERT(dateTime, DATE)) = 1
GROUP BY CURR
```

Comment: Same result. I must describe variables. How display if I do not?